# Checking json output status using if in php

Tags: json, api, cpanel

I'm using cPanel xml-api class and its json output gives me the following when creating a user account,

I've passed an invalid username here .

What I require is to store the output in a variable and check if it is successful or not,

Output :

```
{"result":[{"status":0,"statusmsg":"Sorry, that username is reserved.","rawout":null,"options":null}]}
```

if($result->status=1) then it will print success otherwise print failure also is it possible to print the errormsg with the failure msg.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to start by `decoding` the response string into PHP types:

```
$result = json_decode($result);
```

Then, you can pull the status of the first result as if it were nested in an array:

```
$status = $result[0]['status'];
if ($status === 1) {
  echo 'OK';
}
```

Comment: Also when i used your code i get this error - Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: found out the it should be json_decode($result,true) when referring as an array.